# Umbraco template not being created from new MVC View in existing application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have an existing project that is running Umbraco 7.10

Whenever we create a new view, the template is not created in Umbraco (but new Partials are) when we deploy to existing environments

We are not using uSync at present and the umbracoSettings.config template section is set to Mvc rather than WebForms

What is stopping the template being present in Umbraco? is it something I am missing in the cmsTemplate table?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the template in Umbraco and then manually include in your VS project not the other way around.

There is a db component to a template/view which only gets created if you do things from Umbraco rather than VS. Partials do not have a db component and are simply read from the file system.

uSync would be a good move if you have separate databases for different environments otherwise you will have to add the template to each Umbraco instance.